# Azure AD account had option to send password to another email address - where is this address in user's Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was just recently created as a new user in Microsoft 365 Admin Center (https://admin.microsoft.com/) and during account creation, when setting up password, there was a field to send the password /setup details to me through another email address (my previous email address, outside O365).

I received my new account notification at this other email address, and now this email address gets notifications etc. but when we look at my Azure AD membership, I can't find where this email address is configured in the settings.  Where is this forwarding address being stored?

- We checked Azure Admin portal (portal.azure.com) Authentication contact info for my entry and it's not filled in.
- It's not in Manage User Name or contact information in the https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/users page
- It's not in my account profile anywhere in https://portal.office.com/account/#personalinfo

Totally stumped!  Apologies if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mystery solved: The forwarding was happening through billing notifications setup:
https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/BillingNotifications

Comment: Great finding.. Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 1):

did you check in the account profile under security and privacy? there is an email field there as well. https://portal.office.com/account/#security
if not there. then there is a different spot,
make sure you're logged into portal.office.com 
then go here
https://myaccount.microsoft.com/ 
then click security info. enter your password again, and there is a authentication email there as well.

hope this is what you're looking for.